# Ajax url parametetr using Twig path

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, twig

i have a problem in my twig view when i pass params in the ajax url path,
logically twig is executed before javascript so he didnt recognize the input value passed as parameter. Is there a solution to do this without passing the param in data ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
(function($) {

    var $projectField = $('#project-field-container');

    $projectField.on('change', function() {
        var id_project = $(this).val();
        if('' != id_project) {
            $.ajax({
                url: {{ path('project_field', {'id_project': id_project})}},
                success: function (data) {
                    var content = $('select', data.contentHTML).html();
                    $projectField.html(content).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) for this. It has an interface that is similar or maybe even identical to the Twig `{{ path() }}` and allows you to only expose a small part of the routes to Javascript.

Your js implementation then will be able to generate routes [as you can see in the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generating-uris).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to assign the twig statement to a js variable earlier (before the call to ajax) like this :

```
var path = {{ path('project_field', {'id_project': id_project})}};
```

and then use

```
url: path
```

in your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
data-url="{{ path('project_field', {'id_project': id_project}) }}"
```

and access it through your js

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

(function($) {

var $projectField = $('#project-field-container');

$projectField.on('change', function() {

    var url = $(this).data('url');

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data) {
            var content = $('select', data.contentHTML).html();
                $projectField.html(content).trigger('change');
            },
      error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
})(jQuery);
```