# Generate Javascript with twig on Symfony 3.0 without interfearing with {} in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, requirejs, twig, symfony

Fellows I try ro generate a way that I will be able to get the urls of each ajax call by using twig's path function. The reason I am doing that is because I try to create a single-page application by using Knockout MVVM and require.js therefore I need Ajax calls and I need the urls to be generated dynamically.

The way I do it is that I create a Route:

```
  /**
  *@Route("/ajax.js",name="ajax_calls")
  */
  public function ajax_calls(Request $request)
  {
    $response=$this->render('javascript/ajax_calls.js.twig');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');

    return $response;
  }
```

And I load the specific template (javascript/ajax_calls.js.twig):

```
/**
*Returns the urls of the calls we need
*/
define([],function($)
{

  return {
    /**
    *Urls for the albums (aka image groups)
    */
    'albums':{
              'get':function()
               {
                return "{{path('user_groups')}}";
               },
               'add':function()
               {
                 return "{{path('group_add')}}";
               }
               'delete':function()
               {
                   return "{{path('group_delete')}}";
               }
               'edit':function()
               {
                 return "{{path('group_update')}}";
               }
              },
    /**
    *Urls for the Images
    */
    'images':{
              'add':function(group_id)
              {
                return "{{path('add_images', group_id='^group_id^')}}".replace("^group_id^",group_id);
              },
              'delete':function()
              {
                return "{{path('delete_images')}}";
              }
             }
  };
});
```

I use fefine because I want to be able to be loaded with require.js and as you can See I try to generate an Object that returns the urls for a specific part of an single page application.

But somehow on line:

```
    'albums':{
```

There's is a conflict and I do not know how to escape it.

The specific Error I get is:

```
Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in main.js.twig at line 11.
```

Do you know how to fix this problem or an alternative way to get the urls as a Javascript Object (by generating them dynamically)?

Note: I also seen the https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md as posted on [Ajax url parametetr using Twig path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653062/ajax-url-parametetr-using-twig-path)

But It does not help me on how I desighned the application (I use view models and I want to keep the view models as clear as possible from urls and load them externally).

Also I will be grad for an Alternate way to do that.

---

### Edit 1:

I tried with:

```
/**
*Returns the urls of the calls we need
*/
define([],function($)
{

  return {
    /**
    *Urls for the albums (aka image groups)
    */
    'albums': {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
              'get':function()
{% verbatim %}   { {% endverbatim %}
                return "{{path('user_groups')}}";
               },
               'add':function()
               {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
                 return "{{path('group_add')}}";
               }
               'delete':function()
               {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
                   return "{{path('group_delete')}}";
               }
               'edit':function()
               {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
                 return "{{path('group_update')}}";
               }
              },
    /**
    *Urls for the Images
    */
    'images': {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
              'add':function(group_id)
              {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
                return "{{path('add_images', group_id='^group_id^')}}".replace("^group_id^",group_id);
              },
              'delete':function()
              {% verbatim %} { {% endverbatim %}
                return "{{path('delete_images')}}";
              }
             }
  };
});
```

And returns the error:

```
Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in main.js.twig at line 11.
```

---

### Edit2:

I also get the same error with:

```
{% verbatim %}
/**
*Returns the urls of the calls we need
*/
define([],function($)
{

  return {
    /**
    *Urls for the albums (aka image groups)
    */
    'albums':{
{% endverbatim %}
              'get':function()
               {
                return "{{path('user_groups')}}";
               },
               'add':function()
               {
                 return "{{path('group_add')}}";
               }
               'delete':function()
               {
                   return "{{path('group_delete')}}";
               }
               'edit':function()
               {
                 return "{{path('group_update')}}";
               }
{% verbatim %}
              },
    /**
    *Urls for the Images
    */
    'images':{
{% endverbatim %}
              'add':function(group_id)
              {
                return "{{path('add_images', group_id='^group_id^')}}".replace("^group_id^",group_id);
              },
              'delete':function()
              {
                return "{{path('delete_images')}}";
              }
{% verbatim %}
             }
  };
});
{% endverbatim %}
```

---

### Edit 3:

I figured out that I generate an another javascript file. The controller generates it by using the main.js.twig:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl:'{{asset('')}}',
  paths:{
    'text':'assets/vendor/js/text.min',

    'knockout':["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min",'assets/vendor/js/knockout.min'],
    'pager':"{{asset('assets/vendor/js/pager.min')}}",
    'jquery':"{{asset('assets/vendor/js/jquery.min')}}",
    'boostrap':"{{asset('assets/vendor/js/bootstrap.min')}}",

    'ajax':"{{path('ajax_calls')|replace('.js':'')}}",

    {% block Viewmodels %}
    {% endblock %}

    'compMessage':'assets/js/components/message',
    'extBooleanToggle':'assets/js/extenders/booleanToggle',
  },
  shim:{
    'pager':['knockout'],
    'bootstrap':['jquery'],
    },
  waitSeconds: 200,
});

{% block initFunction %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the problem that generates is the line:

```
'ajax':"{{path('ajax_calls')|replace('.js':'')}}",
```

What I try to do in this line is to generate a "fake" .js file without the .js in order to require.js to load it with .js extention.

Comment: Did you tried to add a space between `album:` and `{` ? It would be `album: {` instead of `album:{`. Not that the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) should suit your needs exactly, it helps to properly generate routes in views.

Comment: you could try the `verbatim` tag marks sections as being raw text that should not be parsed. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Comment: I tried both your Ideas same error as you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the line:

```
'ajax':"{{path('ajax_calls')|replace('.js':'')}}",
```

with:

```
'ajax':"{{path('ajax_calls')|trim('.js')}}",
```

On main.js.twig and works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

If that's really your code... you're missing 2 commas, one after the **add** method and another after the **delete**:

```
{
    'get': function ()
    {
        return "{{path('user_groups')}}";
    },
    'add': function ()
    {
        return "{{path('group_add')}}";
    },
    'delete': function ()
    {
        return "{{path('group_delete')}}";
    },
    'edit': function ()
    {
        return "{{path('group_update')}}";
    }
}
```

It's **not** a **twig** related problem at all I think.

Comment: But I get the error from twig. Twig must return the text as is even if it is the "wrong" javascript text.